# Pass variable within dictionary using other dictionary value

Tags: ansible

How does one assign a value containing a variable to a dictionary key, when it is using another dictionary value as a parameter.

Example

```yaml
---
- name: Test vars
  hosts: ['localhost']
  vars:
    foo:
      a: "foo a value"
      b: "{{ a }}"
  tasks:
  - name: Fix owneship and permission issue with sudoers file
    debug:
      msg: Print {{ foo.b }}
```

I have tried the following:

```yaml
vars:
  foo:
    a: " foo a value"
    b: "{{ foo.a }}"
```

```yaml
vars:
  foo:
    a: " foo a value"
    b: "{{ foo['a'] }}"
```

```yaml
vars:
  foo:
    a: " foo a value"
    b: "{{ a }}"
```

None of the above work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fulfil this requirement using YAML only, via a couple [node anchor](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#id2785586) / [alias node](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#id2786196).

In YAML syntax, you can add an anchor before a value, then you can reference it via an alias node.

An anchor is denoted by the `&` indicator:

```yaml
some_key: $anchor_name value
```

While an alias is denoted by the `*` indicator:

```yaml
some_other_key: *anchor_name
```

---

So, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: foo.b
  vars:
    foo:
      a: &foo_a "foo a value"
      b: *foo_a
```

This yields the expected:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  foo.b: foo a value
```

---

But, indeed, it is just an anchor and alias, you won't be able to compose a value from a literal plus a variable or compose based on multiple variables, e.g. if you want

```yaml
####
# Please note that this is a counterexample and won't work
####

mydict:
  foo: "example {{ mydict.bar }}"
  bar: 123
```

or

```yaml
####
# Please note that this is a counterexample and won't work
####

mydict:
  foo: "{{ mydict.bar }}{{ mydict.baz }}"
  bar: 123
  baz: 456
```

You are left with no option, as this is something Ansible does not plan to allow:

> This is expected and not something that we plan on changing. You cannot create a self referential variable.

<sup>[*Quoted from sivel, maintainer of Ansible, on their issue tracker*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280#issuecomment-450901757)</sup>