# Is it possible to reference a variable defined inside a vars file in that vars file itself?

Tags: ansible

In a vars file, I would like to use a variable defined inside that vars file itself, like this:

```yaml
---
# file vars/users.yml

timestamp:
  sep2023: 1693864800 # date --date=09/05/2023 +%s
  
users:
  a_user:
    name: a_user
    passwd: $6$FF.DN/vbue.2i9/vla6h8xpZhx4L/dppBbnnCWN8hZ0
    uid: 3007
    comment: log receiver
    expires: '{{timestamp.sep2023}}'
```

but when I load it with `ansible.builtin.include_vars` like this :

```yaml
tasks:
    - name: load user base
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        file: users.yml
        name: users
```

I get the error:

> 'timestamp' is undefined

How can I do that?

Comment: [_`name`: The name of a variable into which assign the included vars._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#parameter-name) => `users.timestamp`

Comment: Or [_If omitted (null) they will be made top level vars._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#parameter-name) => remove the line `name: users`

Comment: If I write :     expires: "{{users.timestamp.sep2023}}", the error is : recursive loop detected in template string: {{users.timestamp.sep2023}}"}

Comment: Then, use the second option, aka  assign variables at the top level, by omitting the `name` parameter. Or use a [YAML anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369237/2123530).

Comment: And if you want to understand what happens to you: by using the `name: users`, you end up with one variable containing both `users.users` and `users.timestamp`, **but** an Ansible variable [cannot self reference](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280#issuecomment-474376506), so your best bet is to let go of the `name` parameter.

Comment: Ok, it's work at the top level, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's work without name, like this :

```
tasks:
    - name: load user base
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        file: users.yml
```

So here is a solution. But no solution found if I want to keep a namespace. With :

```
tasks:
    - name: load user base
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        file: users.yml
        name: users
```

and :

```
---
# file vars/users.yml

timestamp:
  sep2023: 1693864800 # date --date=09/05/2023 +%s
  
users:
  a_user:
    name: a_user
    passwd: $6$FF.DN/vbue.2i9/vla6h8xpZhx4L/dppBbnnCWN8hZ0
    uid: 3007
    comment: log receiver
    expires: '{{users.timestamp.sep2023}}'
```

I get the error :

```
recursive loop detected in template string: {{users.timestamp.sep2023}}"}
```

If I choose another name for the namespace, different from the filename, like :

```
  tasks:
    - name: load user base
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        file: users.yml
        name: users2
```

then :

```
expires: '{{user.timestamp.sep2023}}'
```

fails with the error :

```
'users' is undefined
```

and :

```
expires: '{{user2.timestamp.sep2023}}'
```

fails with the error :

```
recursive loop detected in template string: {{users2.timestamp.sep2023}}"}
```

Comment: As I said in the comments, if you want to achieve it in the same dictionary, [use a YAML anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369237/2123530).

Answer (score 0):

The true solution is to use YAML anchor (thanks to β.εηοιτ.βε), regardless of any ansible consideration :

```
---
# file vars/users.yml

timestamp:
  - &sep2023 1693864800 # date --date=09/05/2023 +%s

users:
  a_user:
    name: a_user
    passwd: $6$FF.DN/vbue.2i9/vla6h8xpZhx4L/dppBbnnCWN8hZ0
    uid: 3007
    comment: log receiver
    expires: *sep2023
```