# How can I use a variable in the same node for dictionary definition in Ansible?

Tags: ansible-2.x

In Ansible variable definitions, I don't known if it is possible, but, I would like to refer, in dictionary variable an other variable in the same node.

I'm trying to define my of dictionary like this :

```yaml
applications:
   app1:
     name: app1
     var1: foo
     var2: "The application {{item.value.name}}"
    app2: ...
```

But `{{item.value.name}}` does not work for variable `var2`. I have this error:

> 'item' is undefined

Same error if I try with `{{name}}`:

> 'name' is undefined"

How can I reference `name` in `var2`?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You can reference other keys with YAML anchors, but you cannot compose a value from another key. Related: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible pass variable within dictionary using other dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367593/ansible-pass-variable-within-dictionary-using-other-dictionary-value)

Comment: I try the anchor it works but i want to compose myvar2 with some text or variables and var1. In this case it doen't work.
And the second exemple 
applications:
   app1:
     name: app1
     var1: foo
     var2: "The application {{applications.app1.name}}"
    app2:..
 doesn't work :  original message: recursive loop detected in template string

Comment: i'm in the same case of https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50280.
I think there no solution for my case. 
Thanks β.εηοιτ.βε

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `with_dict` loop and `item.key` variable. Let me add an example to it:

```
applications:
   app1:
     name: app1
     var1: foo
     var2: "The application {{ applications[item.key].name }}"
    app2:...
tasks:
 - name: Print application details
     debug:
       msg: "{{ item.value.var2 }}"
   with_dict: "{{ applications }}"
```

Comment: Same result : l"message: recursive loop detected in template string"
Thanks